# Extract last value from an array of objects using monogdb query language?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm new to Mongo. By new I mean couple of hours new.

Basically I have this document structure:

```
{     
      _id: ObjectId("614513461af3bf569fdc420e"),
      item: 'postcard',
      status: 'A',
      size: { h: 10, w: 15.25, uom: 'cm' },
      instock: [ { warehouse: 'B', qty: 15 }, { warehouse: 'C', qty: 35 } ] 
}
```

I would like if possible to extract particular field (i.e. its value) from `instock`'s last element. In this case I just need to extract `35` i.e. `qty` field.

I have managed to do this:

```
db.offer.find( { _id: ObjectId("614513461af3bf569fdc420e") }, { instock: 1, _id: 0} )
```

Which results in :

```
{ instock: [ { warehouse: 'B', qty: 15 }, { warehouse: 'C', qty: 35 } ] }
```

I don't know how to reach to last object in array and than its `qty` field and everything needs to be as single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Aggregate solution**
(requires MongoDB 5, else query would be a little bigger)

Query

- filter for the `_id` with the `$match` stage
- get last element of `$instock`, and then field `qty`
- project to keep only the above part

*we do it like we would do it in a programming language, get last element, and get a field value.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pydwcY4JC-3)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
{"$match": {"_id": ObjectId("614513461af3bf569fdc420e")}},
{
  "$project": {
  "_id": 0,
  "qty": {"$getField": {"field": "qty","input": {"$last": "$instock"}}}
  }
}
])
```

Comment: Why do you use `$getField`? It's an overkill. Use `{$last: "$instock.qty"}`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Your solution also works.

Comment: `$instock.qty` is an array. and if it had like 1000 members, it would look like 1000 projections.Here we only need 1 projection in the last member, so it looked faster and simpler way, i didn't benchmark it to be sure, but looks more logical to me.But `$instock.qty` would be fine also.